# How to free process allocation

Tags: chromium

I noticed that after a while, chromium eat up all my RAM but does not free it when I close every tabs, see: [htop screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxRpA.png)

The parent process is allocating almost half of my RAM even if all the tab closed.

I (wrongly) thought that chromium tabs were sandboxed, and so if I closed them all, all they allocated memory would be freed. But this does not seems to be the case.

Why does the main chromium process is still having all this allocation ? How to free it ?

- Killing the process is not a solution
- sending some kind of `SIGFREE` would be nice

Comment: Do not worry. Linux management is very good and the memory will be made available to other processes if needed.

Comment: Welcome to askUbuntu. Posting images of output may not be a good idea. Consider adding text instead of images for command line output